# How can I use volume charge density to find charge density constant knowing charge $Q$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

I have an insulating sphere of radius R that has a total charge Q. 
It is distributed as  $\rho$= $\rho_0*r^4$. I know that the charge is equal to Q and I'm trying to solve for $\rho_0$. I've tried to integrate like this $\rho_0$ $\int r^4 \ d \tau$ = $Q$. I end up getting  $\rho $ multiplied by the volume of a sphere, therefore:
 $$\rho_0(4/3)*\pi*r^7 = Q.$$ 
I manipulate and then solve for $\rho_0$. Therefore: $$\rho_0 =  3Q/(r^3 4 \pi) .$$ I just want to make sure this is correct and that this is something that is acceptable as an answer. I have to use this to find the Electric field as a function of $r$ later.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to do the integral correctly. In the integral
$$
\int r^4\mathrm dV=\iint r^6\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\Omega
$$
the $r$ is a function of space that needs to be integrated over. The result will **not** be $R^4\times \tfrac{4\pi}{3}R^3$ (for $R$ the outer radius of the sphere).

Your result is also plainly incorrect from dimensional analysis considerations. Since $\rho=\rho_0 r^4$, it follows that $\rho_0$ should have dimensions of $\text{charge}/(\text{length})^7$, which your final result doesn't. This is a useful check on your final result, but you should also be aware that even correct dimensions on your final result are not a guarantee that you have performed the integral correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have a different integration to do than here because the volume element in spherical coordinates is $$r^2 \sin(\theta) dr d\theta d\phi$$ Because there is no dependence on angle (at least none mentioned) the angular integral will give you $4\pi$, and the $r$ integral should give $r^7/7$, so that overall $\rho(4/7)\pi r^7 = Q$